# How to keep internet traffic from routing over a VPN?

Tags: windows-7, networking, internet, vpn

Hello we are a little development startup. We deal with a lot of VPNs to our clients.

What we do:

1. Connect VPN
2. Use remote desktop to connect to a client's server
3. Update/configure our program
4. Connect to their SQL Server instance on their network (to do configuration for our proprietary program)
5. Disconnect

There is a minor problem though in that when we connect a VPN, all of the internet traffic from that computer is routed though the VPN. We want to just route through to the local network. It's not a big issue, but it's a bit of a privacy concern and is annoying.

How can we do this in Windows 7 Professional?

Answer (score 5):

On the Networking Tab of the VPN Properties, highlight Internet Protocol TCP/IP properties, click advanced, and uncheck "**Use default gateway on remote network**".

This also has to be configured and supported by the VPN server itself or it won't work.

Comment: The whole process depends on the fact if your VPN server allows split tunnelling or not